# vector insert vs push_back performance issue

Tags: c++, vector, stl, insert, push-back

When I profiled my program, I discovered a bottleneck at:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    vec->push_back(buffer[i]);
}
```

The for-loop lies in a function which is called 100k times.
After replacing it with the following code, the performance increase was enormous.
(The code above was taking 10% of the overall time. The code below takes 0.34%)

```
vec->insert(vec->end(), buffer, buffer + len);
```

The vector in question has the following type: `vector<char>* vec`

Can anybody shed some light on why the second version is so much faster?

**I have also tried reserving space in the first version, but there were no observable improvements.**

Comment: Because in the second case it is known in adavnce how many elements will be needed, so the vector can perform one single allocation. Just a wild guess.

Comment: You may speed up the first version by calling `vec.reserve(len)` before the loop....

Comment: Since the type involved is `char`, the `insert` operation can, in theory, be reduced to the equivalent of a single allocation (if needed) followed by a single `memcpy`. But the first example is going to involve `len` separate operations on the vector plus some amount of loop overhead. Tracing into the standard library code may reveal what's actually happening.

Comment: @dlf You should put that comment in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without a ton of data, it's really difficult to say definitively why one piece of nontrivial code executes faster than another, especially when third-party code is involved (the internal `vector` code, in this case). But you can usually make some guesses.

Since you state that `reserve`ing ahead of time made no difference, my guess is that it just boils down to the number of operations required. In your original code, as a first approximation, there are always going to be `len` indexing operations into `buffer`, `len` calls to `push_back`<sup>*</sup>, and some amount of overhead from running the loop. However, the same is not necessarily true of the call to `insert`. A naive implementation of that function might simply walk an iterator across the range and call `push_back` for each value, in which case you would expect to see roughly equivalent performance. However, a more savvy implementation might realize that the operation boils down to copying a single contiguous run of `len` bytes and make use of machine instructions that can effectively achieve this as a single operation (possibly preceded by a resize/copy if the initial buffer size is too small). But the only way to know for sure would be to look at the actual standard library and/or machine code involved.

You didn't mention what compiler you're using, but just for the heck of it I implemented something like your code in VS2012 and traced in. `insert` did eventually make use of a single call to `memmove` to perform the copy.

---

<sup>*</sup>This is an approximation because, if `push_back` is implemented as an inline function *and* your compiler settings allow it to be inlined, the optimizer could have a field day with that loop. This sort of thing is what I was getting at when I said that reasoning about performance can be tricky without a lot of concrete data.

Answer (score -1):

Vector use an array as their underlying storage. So, it will automatically
expand their array size by a factor of 2 before when it reach the end of array
while using method like push_back.

But in case of insert, vector will prepare enough storage for insertion because vector knows how many elements will be inserted. 
It means that only 1 time expand occur.